# Artifactory BootStrapping

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am containerizing our Artifactory server. I am using the bootstrap file to get the initial configuration for our image. Things like repositories, ldap, etc.

This seems to work fine. But I am wondering how to bootstrap the permissions? It doesn't seem to be stored in the config.xml files?

The LDAP configuration is really a little useless without being able to use the groups along with the defined permissions which each group will have.

Has anyone done anything along these lines?

Comment: Have you looked at the security.xml? Check out these APIs (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-SecurityConfiguration(Deprecated)) which lets you get and set the security descriptor

Comment: Thanks I will have a look at it ;-)

Comment: Hi, Thanks. That is the key!